# How to calculate the number of hours that are 'night shift' hours Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to work out how many hours should be counted as 'night shift' where night shift starts at 23:00 and finishes at 06:00.

We have:

```
shift_id, start_datetime, end_datetime
1233, '2019-10-01 23:30:00', 2019-10-02 07:30:00
1234, '2019-10-01 22:00:00', 2019-10-02 04:00:00
```

The desired outcome for the 2 examples above would be

```
shift_id, night_hrs, reg_hrs
1233, 5.5, 1.5
1234, 5, 1
```

I'm really struggling to figure this one out so any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 2):

I would use a [timestamp range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) and the intersection with the defined nightshift to calculate this.

```
select shift_id,
       start_datetime, end_datetime,
       upper(in_night) - lower(in_night) as time_during_night
from (       
  select shift_id, 
         start_datetime, end_datetime,
         tsrange(start_datetime, end_datetime)  * tsrange(start_datetime::date + time '23:00', end_datetime::date + time '06:00') in_night
  from data
) t
```

`tsrange(start_datetime, end_datetime)` creates a timestamp range and `tsrange(start_datetime::date + time '23:00', end_datetime::date + time '06:00')` creates the coresponding range for those dates for the night shift.

The `*` operator then calculates the [intersection](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) between those two ranges. The outer query then simply subtracts the lower end of that range from the upper, yielding an [interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) that contains the duration during the night shift.

The derived table (sub-query) is only there, so that I don't have to repeat the expression for the ranges when doing the subtraction.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ad3eda66b1214ff82bbb83a74bd1193d)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tested this out but came across an error when the shift is not over 2 days - ```ERROR:  range lower bound must be less than or equal to range upper bound```

for example... the following shift where it ends at 23:30 and therefore is 1 hour into night.

(1235, '2019-10-01 20:00:00', '2019-10-01 23:30:00')

Answer (score 0):

Your logic should be similar to this,

```
Case when cast(end_datetime as time)>=06:00:00 then (cast(enddate as date) + 06:00:00) else end_datetime end
-
Case when cast(start_datetime as time)<=23:30:00 then (cast(startdate as date)+ 23:30:00) else start_datetime end as Night_hrs
```